# Airplay sample Audio

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, core-audio

In my app,i need to generate video with audio. Now i am using Air Play Sample But its contains only generate video only and i need to generate video with audio.Any one help me to solve with problem.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to increase your accept rate.

Secondly, this is quite a lot what you are asking for. I'm not familiar with Air Play, but my suggestion would be to start with the [SpeakHere project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html). That will get you familiarised with core-audio and give you a template for accessing the audio input.

As for the visual aspect I highly recommend [O'Reilly's 3D Programming book](http://iphone-3d-programming.labs.oreilly.com/) which provides a lot of example code.

It will take a bit of time to assimilate both materials, but you'll end up with a better application.